# Action delegate created during for loop not respecting the "for variable" value when used as parameter in the delegated method

Tags: c#, loops, delegates

Noob here, apologies if I'm not using terminology correctly...

Each code block below starts with a list of letters `{ "a", "c" }` and creates an action delegate to later insert `"b"` prior to `"c"`.

I find that when I use the "for variable", `i`, for the index parameter of `List.Insert()`, the value passed is not respected when I call the action delegate later on.  But if I capture `i` in a new `int` and pass that when creating the action delegate, then the value is respected.  Further, if I inspect the variables `i` and `index` on the iteration where the action delegate is created, they both hold the same value: `1`.

I would expect that both code blocks would return "abc", but obviously they don't.

**Why is the behavior is different between the two sets of code?**

This code outputs "acb":

```
        public void Test()
        {
            List<string> letters = new List<string>() { "a", "c" };
            List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.Count; i++)
            {
                string letter = letters[i];
                if (letter == "c")
                {
                    actions.Add(new Action(() => letters.Insert(i, "b")));
                }
            }

            for (int i = actions.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
                actions[i]();

            foreach (var letter in letters)
                Debug.Write(letter);
        }
```

This code outputs "abc":

```
        public void Test()
        {
            List<string> letters = new List<string>() { "a", "c" };
            List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.Count; i++)
            {
                string letter = letters[i];
                if (letter == "c")
                {
                    int index = i; // Using "index" instead of i when creating the action
                    actions.Add(new Action(() => letters.Insert(index, "b")));
                }
            }

            for (int i = actions.Count - 1; i > -1; i--)
                actions[i]();

            foreach (var letter in letters)
                Debug.Write(letter);
        }
```

Comment: It's called closure https://www.simplethread.com/c-closures-explained/

Comment: @insane_developer, thank you! This information has been very helpful